# Github: Marking conflict as resolved does not merge the changes

Tags: git, github, version-control, pull-request, conflict

I have done a PR and now I am resolving a conflict on Github.
After fixing the conflict I click on Mark as resolved:
[image]
It says that the conflict has been resolved:
[image]
But, when I refresh the conflicts page, I see that the conflict is still there, as if I haven't changed anything:
[image]
Any idea, what's going-on?

Comment: Are you actually doing something about the conflict?

Comment: Yes, I resolveed it.

Comment: Resolving doesn’t mean the conflict is gone. Did you edit the file?

Comment: Yes, I did. I know this is a strange behavior as I have resolved other conflicts before.

Comment: What about trying to resolve it locally? Using git on the command line?

Comment: This has nothing to do with the answer, but: did you check the [tag:conflict] tag's information about when to use the tag on a question? If not, I suggest you should take a look now. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have not used the GitHub "resolve a conflict without using Git yourself" web page, but [its documentation](https://docs.github.com/en/github/collaborating-with-issues-and-pull-requests/resolving-a-merge-conflict-on-github) says that you must click "commit merge" before the conflicts will actually be resolved.  This makes a lot of sense for internal-to-Git reasons.

It does seem as though simply *reloading* the page should preserve resolutions-so-far, so that you just keep going.  To make this work well, though, GitHub will need to store some sort of information in your browser (cookies, etc.); blocking this will cause the reload to lose track of what you have done so far.

I would recommend learning to use command-line Git, rather than poking about with these web interfaces, which are invariably poorer than the Git tooling.  The paucity of abilities that the web interfaces provide are a significant part of the *reason* the web interfaces are easier to use (just as it's easier to drive an automatic transmission car, than a manual-transmission one, for instance: since there is that much less you *can* do, there is that much less that you *have to* do).